# OS X 10.8.5: Can I move icons around in the dock and not have them stay there when the apps are closed?

Tags: macos, dock

Whenever I drag an open application's icon in the dock to another place in the dock, it thinks that means I want it to stay in the dock even if the app closes.

Is it possible for me to change this behavior? I like to arrange my icons in a certain way, but I don't like icons in the dock whose apps are not open.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all *closed* apps from the Dock (even if they are set to 'Keep in Dock') with the following command:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dock static-only
```

You can [assign a hotkey to run this](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x), or set up a launch agent to run this regularly.